# How does SQL Server handle an update with no change?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run an update statement using a case statement. 99% of time there will be no change. So I was wondering about the performance.

For example if I run

```
update <table> 
set field1 = field1
```

does it copy field1 and then write it into field1 or does it do nothing?

Comment: Why not excluding rows that don't need to be changed with a `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the database and in SQL Server, the answer is yes.

You should filter the values instead.  Instead of:

```
update t
    set x = (case when a = b then c else x end);
```

You should do:

```
update t
    set x = c
    where a = b;
```